The windows partition seems to return an incorrect result
I thought that there would be a context switch each time present changed for the Id since I was looking the contiguous range of dates with present being 1 and resetting the row_number() each time a sub-context changes Present from 1 or 0 and vice versa.  As well as the Id, changes to a new Id.
Why isn't the correct answer for 2 2024-03-13 1 1 and not 2 2024-03-13 1 2 ---wrong should be one?
id date present RowNumberPresent
2 2024-03-11 1 1 --- Correct
2 2024-03-12 0 1 --- Correct
2 2024-03-13 1 2 ---wrong should be one?
;with RankEmpolyeeAttendance
as (select id,
date,present,
row_number() over (partition by id, present order by date) as RowNumberPresent
from dbo.attendance
)
SELECT r.id,
r.date,
r.present,
r.RowNumberPresent FROM RankEmpolyeeAttendance as r
order by r.id,
r.date

id  date    present RowNumberPresent
1   2024-03-12  1   1
1   2024-03-13  1   2
1   2024-03-14  1   3
1   2024-03-15  0   1
2   2024-03-11  1   1
2   2024-03-12  0   1
2   2024-03-13  1   2  -- This should 1 not 2
3   2024-03-14  1   1
3   2024-03-15  1   2

enter image description here

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

You are partitioning by id, present so all rows with the same pair of those values are grouped together. "resetting the row_number() each time a sub-context changes" no why would it do that? It's simply grouping the rows together using partition by then numbering according to the order by. It sounds like you want some kind of gaps-and-islands result instead.
